# Is there a possible that I can transfer a certain html tag to another position using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have here a navigation bar with a caret beside it. And I wanted to change this one dynamically using jquery. When on click, the activated menu transfers to the one being clicked. What I wanted to happen is I want to move also the arrow to the clicked menu in the navigation bar. How do I do that in jquery?

```
                         <div class = "side-nav-bar content">
                            <a class="active-menu" href="javascript:;">체육학</a><i class="arrow right"></i>
                            <a href="javascript:;">전공소개</a>
                            <a href="javascript:;">졸업 후 진로</a>
                            <a href="javascript:;">교육 프로그램</a>
                            <a href="javascript:;">교수소개</a>
                    </div>

                          $('.side-nav-bar a').click(function(){
            $('.side-nav-bar a').not(this).removeClass('active-menu');
            $(this).addClass('active-menu');
            $('arrow').insertAfter('active-menu');
    }); 

                          .arrow {
                        border: solid white;
                        border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
                        display: inline-flex;
                        padding: 3px;
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 23px;
                        right: 10px;
                         }

                          .right {
                            transform: rotate(-45deg);
                            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                            }
```

Comment: correction: I WANTED ALSO TO MOVE THE ARROW TO THE ACTIVATED MENU.

Answer (score 0):

You almost done it `$('.arrow').insertAfter(this);` OR while you add the `active-menu` class to the clicked `a` you can also use `$('.arrow').insertAfter(".active-menu");`

```js
$('.side-nav-bar a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.side-nav-bar a').not(this).removeClass('active-menu');
  $(this).addClass('active-menu');
  $('.arrow').insertAfter(this);
});
```

```css
.arrow {
border: solid white;
border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
display: inline-flex;
padding: 3px;
top: 23px;
right: 10px;
color : red;
background : red;
}

.right {
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "side-nav-bar content">
  <a class="active-menu" href="javascript:;">체육학</a><i class="arrow right"></i>
  <a href="javascript:;">전공소개</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">졸업 후 진로</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">교육 프로그램</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">교수소개</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! it worked but the arrow did not appear on the new selected menu.

Comment: @AlexDeneris the problem in the absolute position .. you can remove it or you can take a look at [@Kosh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300799/3385827)

Answer (score 0):

You might get rid of `<i class="arrow right"></i>` and use pseudo-element instead:

```js
$('.side-nav-bar a').click(function() {
  $('.side-nav-bar a').not(this).removeClass('active-menu');
  $(this).addClass('active-menu');
});
```

```css
.side-nav-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: navy
}

a {
  position: relative;
  padding: .5em 2em .5em 1em;
  color: #fff;
}

a.active-menu {
  background: red;
}

a.active-menu:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px;
  top: .9em;
  right: .5em;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-nav-bar content">
  <a class="active-menu" href="javascript:;">체육학</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">전공소개</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">졸업 후 진로</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">교육 프로그램</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">교수소개</a>
</div>
```